# Batch file that adds part of the Filename to the csv list

Tags: csv, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file which does the following things within a CSV:

1. For deleting the first row I'm using this bat:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b /on "*.csv"') do (
    more /e +1 "%%i">"%%i.tmp" 
    del "%%i" && ren "%%i.tmp" "%%i"
)
exit /b
```

2. For deleting the last row, I'm using this second bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.csv) do (
find /v "Dow" < %%a >> %%~Na_.csv
)
```

3. Split the CSV that looks like this:

```
10/14/13,16.5,17.15,15.7,15.9,0.2,59474,38217
```

...and only keep the first the 5. the 7. and the 8. number after the comma.

I'm using my third bat for it:

```
@Echo off
For %%F in (*.csv) do ( 
    (for /f "delims=" %%A in (%%F) do Call :Split %%A
    ) > "%~dp0%%~nF_fixed.csv"
)
goto :Eof
:Split
Echo(%1,%5,%7,%8
```

This results in:

```
10/14/13,15.9,59474,38217
```

4. Finally I need to a add an entry behind the last number that is based on the filename, I need the first 2 characters then the 4. and 5. and afterwars the 3.

So if for example the filename is: `abc12_somerandomstuff` it should finally look like this:

```
10/14/13,15.9,59474,38217,ab12c
```

I Googled for several ideas but I can't get it to work, can you guys help me with it?

I also tried to merge the 3 bats into one but it didnt work so I kept using all three one after the other so if you could merge them properly it would be awesome.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: To clarify, are you staying that all three bat files work as expected and intended, but you just want somebody to merge them into one for you?

Comment: Didn't try, but the following should be able to replace your three scripts: `For %%F in (*.csv) do (`, `(for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,5,7,8 delims=," %%A in ('findstr /v "Dow" %%F') do @echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D`, `) > "%~dp0%%~nF_fixed.csv"`, `)`

Comment: Yes the first three bats are working fine and it would be nice if someone could merge it but the main problem i still got is the 4. part to write parts of the filename into the csv

Comment: See `set /?` for how to do substring operations.

Comment: Thank you Stephan the merge approach works perfectly!

Comment: This site is for help fixing a specific issue with your code, and all of your code is working. You can close your off topic question now, or edit the question to remove all three working batch files, and add the code you tried in their place.